# Getting Access to HttpServletRequest object in restful web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf, restful-authentication

I can get access to the HttpServlet Request object in a soap web service as follows:
Declaring a private field for the WebServiceContext in the service implementation, and annotate it as a resource:

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;
```

To get the HttpServletRequet object, I write the code as below:

```
MessageContext ctx = context.getMessageContext();
HttpServletRequest request =(HttpServletRequest)ctx.get(AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_REQUEST);
```

But these things are not working in a restful web service. 
I am using Apache CXF for developing restful web service. Please tell me how can I get access to HttpServletRequest Object.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd recommend using `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext`

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext;

...
// add the attribute to your implementation
@Context 
private MessageContext context;

...
// then you can access the request/response/session etc in your methods
HttpServletRequest req = context.getHttpServletRequest();
HttpServletResponse res = context.getHttpServletResponse()
```

You can use the `@Context` annotation to flag other types (such as ServletContext or the HttpServletRequest specifically). See [Context Annotations.](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-basics.html#JAX-RSBasics-Contextannotations)

Comment: In the Jersey implementation, `MessageContext` does not work. But you can still use `@Context HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: I could not get your example to work. I was only able to get a reference to the HttpServletRequest by adding it as a method parameter decorated with the @Context annotation as shown below.

Answer (score 4):

use this code for access request and response for each request:

```
@Path("/User")
public class RestClass{

    @GET
    @Path("/getUserInfo")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getUserrDetails(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
            @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
        String username = request.getParameter("txt_username");
        String password = request.getParameter("txt_password");
        System.out.println(username);
        System.out.println(password);

        User user = new User(username, password);

        return Response.ok().status(200).entity(user).build();
    }
... 
}
```