# How to capture XML POST message body before it is processed by CXF?

Tags: java, rest, cxf, resttemplate

I would like to see the XML that is submitted with my `POST` request that is processed using `jax-rs` and `Apache CXF`:

```
@POST
@Path("entity/register")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response registerEntity(Entity entity ) { ... }
```

I call the service using `Spring` [`RestTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html):

```
String postURI = "...";
Entity entity = new Entity(...);
restTemplate.postForLocation(postURI, entMap);
```

So both the RestTemplate and CXF encapsulate the boilerplate functions of preparing and parsing the request. However, I would like to see either how the RestTemplate marshals the object into XML or how CXF unmarshals it but preferably I would like to be able to see the entire HTTP request including the headers.

The reason I would like that is so that I can mimic the request in other clients, such as `Python`, `Chrome Poster` etc. More specifically, I would like to write a Python script that will be posting the same XML format to the same REST service and there I do not have Java frameworks to encapsulate the (un)marshaling for me.

I am using `Tomcat 7` but was hoping to find a way to do it in Java (debugging) and without logging all HTTP requests in the Tomcat logs.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873197/getting-access-to-httpservletrequest-object-in-restful-web-service) didn't work for me because the context was not getting injected and remained null.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a series of do-nothing [interceptors](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html), one at each Phase, and examine the Message in the debugger at each step along the way. I *believe* that the phase you're looking for is `PRE_PROTOCOL`, but I seem to recall that certain information isn't necessarily available when you'd expect it to be.